# Test-Path Isn't Working

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm having trouble getting Test-Path to work from the pipeline. For some reason the command always evaluates to false and executes the commands contained in the IF statement.

The code looks like this:

```
$BACKUPFOLDER = "F:\TEST\Old\"
Get-ChildItem "$SrcFolder\*.pgp" | Where-Object {!$_.PsIsContainer} | ForEach-Object {
        Add-Content -Path $LOGFILE -Value "`r`n - Decrypting file $_ -"
        Decrypt-Files $_ "$SrcFolder$($_.BaseName)" $Credential $DecryptionLogFile        

        if (!(Test-Path "$BackupFolder$($_.BaseName)")) {
            Add-Content -Path $LOGFILE -Value "`n`rMoving $_ to $BackupFolder"
            Move-Item $_ $BackupFolder
        }
        else {
            Add-Content -Path $LOGFILE -Value "`n`rCould not move $_ to $BackupFolder. Destination file already exists."
        }
```

The error I get is with the Move-Item command:

```
Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

At F:\Scripting\1-Dev\Modules\Include.ps1:505 char:26
+                 Move-Item <<<<  $_ $BackupFolder
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (F:\TEST...201301.xlsx.pgp:FileInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveFileInfoItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

I'm confused because the file already exists in the backup folder, yet for some reason the script still goes through the IF statement and executes the move-item command. Is my syntax bad for Test-Path?

The file I'm decrypting will be named something like VPAS-201301.xlsx.pgp and the file I'm extracting will be VPAS-201301.xlsx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing `$_.BaseName` (that is: name of the file without extension). Use `$_.Name` and you should get expected results.

Comment: Thanks. That was an awfully simple fix. : )